# How to add external jQuery plugin to Angular project

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a question about Angular (v4) and external jQuery plugin. I worked with this jQuery plugin before but with asp.net not Angular. My jQuery plugin consists of 3 elements:

- Folder with plugin files (css, js files)
- Div element that I need to add on my page (`<div id="mapsvg"></div>`)
- jQuery function that I need to add on page and call when page loads (`$('#mapsvg').mapSvg({source: '/maps/usa.svg'});`)

I'm using jQuery plugin from this site: http://mapsvg.com/documentation/jquery/

My question is how can I add this plugin to my Angular project? I tried to do that in new blank project but it does not work.

At this moment I:

1. Added references to script in angular.json -> `"./src/assets/mapsvg/js/mapsvg.js"`
2. declare variable in app.component.ts -> `declare var $: any;`
3. add div element into app.component.html

Right now I receive an error in console that my usa.svg file is not found (404). When I move the svg file into src folder it shows on page but all plugin functionality are not working.

Could anybody please help me with this implementation?

Comment: Angular does not use jQuery - so you have to add jQuery as well.

Comment: Try to see if the plugin you are trying to use has an npm package. Using jQuery on Angular apps is not good practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, You need to install JQuery using `npm install jquery --save` and then in your .ts file add `import * as $ from "jquery";`

This will install jQuery and make it usable. Now , whichever plugin you want, download its source file, keep those files in your assets folder and import that file in your `index.html`
As, for you, you need to keep this codes in your `index.html`

```
<link href="assets/mapsvg.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/mapsvg.min.js"></script>
```

now add this div file, where you want to implement the plugin as

```
<div id="mapsvg"></div>
```

Lastly, call the plugin in ngOnInit() of your component as

```
$('#mapsvg').mapSvg({source: '"assets/mapsvg.svg"'});
```

This much should do the trick. For any query, please comment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. It is now working! But I met with one issue. One of functionality is "popovers" when I added it it not working and in console I received:

Comment: What you received in console? @Sepcio

Comment: Whole error description in my post below (to many characters for comment). I received error: core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: this.contentWrap.nanoScroller is not a function. Answer marked as accepted.

Comment: @sepcio please add a separate question for this new issue. So, that other members of the community also can help you. And please post the link to the new question here in the comments.

Comment: Hi, link to new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000120/nanoscroller-error-after-adding-library-to-angular-project

Answer (score 3):

Add the dependencies in the angular build configuration.
Assuming the app was scaffolded using [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) here an example for Angular 6.x and lower versions.

Depending on the version there is an angular / angular-cli configuration file

Angular 6.x -> **angular.json**

Angular 2.x - 5.x **.angular-cli.json** (a hidden file)

In both files there is a `scripts` section which holds an `Array`.
Add external dependencies there in the order it would be added for `<script>` tags in `HTML`.

[image]

Then finally add the typings definition for jQuery:

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

And use it within your component:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.scss']
})

ngOnInit() { 
    $('#mapsvg').mapSvg({source: '"assets/mapsvg.svg"'});
}
```

Finally the plugin can be called from ngOnInit method or whenever the `<div id="mapsvg"></div>` element appears via method call or on a conditional via`*ngIf`

Comment: I tried the above same way but still having an error 

ngOnInit() { 
   $('#multi-select').multiDatesPicker();
}

Comment: @DeepakPatidar can you pls provide the error message?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: $(...).multiDatesPicker is not a function

Comment: seems the dependency for `multiDatesPicker` wasn't imported

Comment: I have added their dependency on the angualr.json script tag,